# Config Yaml for folders inside folders in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I have this app engine project structure:

[image: project in app engine]

and the this yaml file:

[image: yaml file]

but only `chicken.jpg` will appear in `index.html` and not the images inside `img/cats` or `img/puppys`.

Comment: show `index.html`

Comment: well its a bunch of <img class="responsive-img" id="ipuppys_1" src="img/puppys/puppys_1.jpg">....<img class="responsive-img" id="puppys_12" src="img/puppys/puppys_12.jpg">

Comment: and one last <img class="responsive-img" id="chicken" src="img/chicken.jpg">

Comment: console error show this  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  puppys_1.jpg:1  ..... Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  puppys_12.jpg:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/img` intercepts the others.  Put your url handlers in this order:

```
- url: /img/puppys
  static_dir: img/puppys

- url: /img/cats
  static_dir: img/cats

- url: /img 
  static_dir: img
```

Comment: That was very usefull but I found other problem the images insides puppys and cats folders were this way puppys_1.jpg in the html but inside the folder were puppys_1.JPG this problem I have only seen in App Engine.

Comment: I suppose App engine is not case sensitive with file extension.

Comment: It is case-sensistive

Comment: It is not case sensitive with the file extension